# possibility to change a parameter php? from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a possibility to change a parameter **params: {source:$scope.chartr1}** from the controller - I would like to call a php file with variable parameters.

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.chartr1 = "2010-01-01";
var request = $http.get('xxx.php', {
    params: {source:$scope.chartr1}
 }).success(function(gl){
    $scope.users = gl;    
$scope.chartData = [['Gl', $scope.users]
];
 });
```

Comment: Please explain problem in more detail. You have code that answers the question so it isn't clear what is or isn't working

Comment: Change $scope.chartr1 in file .html does not change xxx.php?source=.....

Comment: Please put some effort into explaining issues properly. If you aren't willing to put the effort in why would anyone be willing to put the effort in to help if they don't understand your problem

Comment: The problem is that xxx.php file is always called with a parameter? Source = 2010-01-01, change the <input ng-model = "chartr1"> not change 2010-01-01.

Comment: So what should change that value? It is hard coded in the controller

Comment: Is there a possibility to change in order to retrieve the value of <input ng-model = "chartr1">

Comment: yes...but the request would need to be made inside a function that depended on `ng-model` being changed by user

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling $http with the default parameter as soon as the controller runs. You should write the $http part in a function and call it only when the user is ready (i.e. after changing the input).

```
$scope.request = function() {
  $http.get('xxx.php', {params: source:$scope.chartr1})...
}

<input ng-model="chartr1">
<button type="button" ng-click="request()">submit</button>
```